# Use one font face from a font family with PIL.ImageFont

Tags: python, fonts, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use bahnschrift to automate making some words on images, but I need bahnschrift semi condensed and not any other font face. I've tried to remove the other font faces so I can just use the bahnschrift semi condensed. It didn't work.

```
title_big = ImageFont.truetype("bahnschrift.ttf", 48, index=0)
```

Anything other than index=0 throws an error.
I'm on windows 10 by the way.

Comment: Nothing about that filename suggests it's the condensed version? Unless you're working with newer "variable axes" fonts, fonts are one file per typeface style, so find the file that for the condensed version of bahnschrift, and then specifically load that. You don't need to remove or uninstall anything: just point PIL to the _actual_ file path.

Comment: I looked deeper at the font and it is a variable axis font

Comment: found the answer - use print(font.get_variation_names()) and then font.set_variation_by_name(<thing>)
I found the one that is suitable for my needs.
also there is font.get_variation_axes() and that works for other fonts as well.

Comment: Yeah, looking at https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html there's a bunch of calls that should help you out here

Comment: If you find answer of your question, please post it as answer by yourself. So users with same issue can find this helpful.

Comment: If you find answer of your question, please post it as answer by yourself. So users with same issue can find this helpful.